# how to import a massive JSON object into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have a couple of really large JSON objects being returned from instagram and I would like to import them in an indexable format into MySQL.

Sample object:
[JSON object](http://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer/627d67)

Is there a tool that will import and build the JSON structure inside of MySQL?
The sub arrays are just linked sub tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at:
https://github.com/adamwulf/json-to-mysql

It takes JSON data, and then creates and stores it inside a table with the correct structure.

Comment: Thanks!   it says I have to wait 4 min to click the button.